# Unreal Engine 4 - Importing pixel art and generating collision

Tags: collision-detection, unreal-engine4

Today, I was trying to import pixel art from [MagicaVoxel](https://ephtracy.github.io/) to Unreal Engine. Import is easy without any problems, but when I try to generete collisions, they are really inaccurate. I get best results with *Auto Convex Collision* tool. I am exporting models from MagicaVoxel using `obj (Wafefront)` format. How to solve this issue?

MagicaVoxel Model
[image: magicavoxel]
Collisions generated by Auto Convex Collision tool
[image: ueimported]
Inaccurate collider
[image: ripblocks]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it in UE 4.16.3 and seems work for me well by default. In **Convex Decomposition** try to set *Accuracy* to `0.5`

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Edit 19.02.2018:**
[Download Test Project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cS6S9URi__xlQu5EpiWOZZksCjsLtkwp/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hmm. It is not working for me. What format are you using to export it from MagicaVoxel?

Comment: obj (Wafefront)

Comment: Sorry for delays with answers! I do not know how to help! In my answer I added link to test project. You could download it and look, maybe it will help you;)